# How to limit the elements inside the div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code where I set elements inside a DIV through a text area. What I want is to set the limit for the elements inside the DIV tag.

Below I have attached the image of the problem:

[image]

From the image, U can see that there are three elements "hat", "Face" and "Hand". I want to set the limit for the div to one. anything more than that should not allowed.

Html:

```
 <div class="tags" id ="tags"></div>
 <div class="input_box">
            <input type="text" name="tags" id="name_tag" class="input_textbox">
            <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
          </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   var render = document.querySelector('#tags');
              var btnset = document.querySelector('#settag');
              var tags = [];
              var nameTag = document.querySelector('#name_tag');

              var $kids =$('#tags');
              var $selected = $kids.children();
              if( $selected.length >= 1){
                $selected.remove();
              }

              btnset.addEventListener('click', () => {

                var color = ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
                render.innerHTML += `<div class="tag" style="border-color: #${color};"><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='fa fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i>

              ${nameTag.value}

              </div>
      `;

  });
```

I tried to set the limit of the div element with the below code:

```
  var $kids =$('#tags');
              var $selected = $kids.children();
              if( $selected.length >= 1){
                $selected.remove();
              }
```

But the above code was not working. I want to set the element limit to one. Can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: You've combined jQuery with JavaScript. I would just go JavaScript these days. If you only want the first div to go in, then set a variable at a higher level scope than the EventListener function, and test against it. Otherwise, change `.innerHTML +=` to `.innerHTML =`. Of course, I wouldn't use `.innerHTML`, but that's another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
   var render = document.querySelector('#tags');
              var btnset = document.querySelector('#settag');
              var tags = [];
              var nameTag = document.querySelector('#name_tag');

              var $kids =$('#tags');
              var $selected = $kids.children();
              if( $selected.length >= 1){
                nameTag.remove();
              }

              btnset.addEventListener('click', () => {

                var color = ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
                console.log(nameTag.value);
                render.innerHTML = `<div class="tag" style="border:solid 1px #${color};"><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></i><i class='fa fa-trash-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i>

              ${nameTag.value}

              </div>
      `;

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags" id ="tags"></div>
 <div class="input_box">
            <input type="text" name="tags" id="name_tag" class="input_textbox">
            <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
          </div>
```